# How do get all customers who haven't placed an order in 5 days in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

This is a different version of what I need but made so that I don't break NDA. The code for what I need should be pretty similar.
The database would essentially be a customer table(first name, last name, phone number, customer id, etc...), an order table(product name, product id, product cost, etc... this one doesn't matter as much), and a middle table that would hold the details for each purchase(customer id, product id, date bought, etc...).
The code I've tried goes as follows.

```
var users = _context.Customers
          .Include(c => c.orders)
          .Where(c => c.orders == 0)
          .Where(o => o.orders
              .OrderBy(o => o.DateBought)
              .Last().DateCreated <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5))
          .AsNoTracking()
          .ToListAsync();
```

I can't really think of anything else and any help would be appreciated. This is for my job, and my boss really doesn't help me out so I can't really ask him. It is important to note that I'm not allowed to use joins(LINQ joins). I'm not sure why, but he is really insistent that it has to be with `.include` and nothing else. I do not need anything other than the customer.

Thank you!

Comment: Technically that Query is going to create SQL with Joins.  Also `Include` is just for including navigation properties, not for filtering purposes.  Maybe your boss just doesn't want you to use Linq Joins https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: Do you need orders in the result also?

Comment: Also why title has 5 days and you substract only 3 days (`DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)`)?

Comment: @GuruStron The 5 days and only subtracting 3 was a typo...

Answer (score 1):

I would try simply using `Any` on orders with corresponding predicate (though not sure if your ORM and database provider will be able to translate this):

```cs
var users = _context.Customers
    .Where(c => !c.orders.Any(o => o.DateCreated > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5))
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: " it has to be with .include and nothing else." - you may want to clarify how your answer satisfy that requirement. (I agree that it makes sense as solution to the problem itself...)

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work. We're using Swagger for the API and SQL Server for the database if that helps any?

Comment: @LEEMCCREADY "this didn't work" is not very helpful. What has happened? Any errors?

Comment: @GuruStron It couldn't translate it into SQL.

Comment: @LeeMcCready don't have SQL Server at my hand. Which version of EF are you using? Works for me with EF Core 5.

Comment: @GuruStron I'm using EF Core 6.

Comment: @LeeMcCready the provided query translates just fine for me with EF Core 6 also. I need to see the full query you are using.

Comment: @GuruStron I figured out the problem. My boss neglected to put a needed relationship into the database again, so your solution may work. I just found this out, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @LeeMcCready NP. Though note that if there is no relationship set up in the EF Core - the only solution is to use `Join` (unless you can set up the relationship)